# Disable build status from jenkins to bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jcasc

In the bitbucket UI there is a column of build status for commits. I don't want my Jenkins to send build statuses to bitbucket.
I configure my jenkins using JCasC, and I can't seem to find the right filed to disable this feature.

I tried disabling plugins like: bitbucket server notifier, bitbucket push and pull request plugin and bitbucket server integration using the jenkins UI, but still when I build a branch, the status it updated in bitbucket

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Sending build commit statuses is a common way to prevent merging of failing code into the target branch and it *should* always be used whenever available. Now to the question - most likely, this feature is configured in the pipeline itself. Please add a simplified example of your Jenkinsfile to your question and describe how it's configured so that the answer could be more targeted.

Comment: I have two Jenkins, one for integration tests and one the actual Jenkins to refer to.
Both Jenkins send the build status to bitbucket but only one is relevant.